# Join two lists according to False condition

Tags: list-manipulation

I am new to MMA. I have a question of joining two lists according to a condition. Suppose I have two lists with same number of elements,

```
l1={a>b,x>y,m>n}
l2={c>d,False,j>k}
```

I want to join the two lists according to a condition: join each list's element according to their positions in the list if they both are inequalities. If there is a False in l2, then ignore both elements of that position. For example,

1. The first element of l1 is a>b, and the first element of l2 is c>d, then the first element of the new list will be {a>b,c>d}.
2. The second element of l1 is x>y, but the second element of l2 is False. So we will ignore position number 2.
3. The third element of l1 is m>n, and the third element of l2 is j>k, then the second element of the new list will be{m>n,j>k}.

Therefore, the new list will be `{{a>b,c>d},{m>n,j>k}}`.

Another example:

```
l3={a>b,c>d,x>y,j>k}
l4={False,False,False,m>n}.
```

Then the new list I want will be `{{j>k,m>m}}`

Thank you in advance for your generous help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of going about it is with a, in some sense, fundamental part of MMA called [pattern matching](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html) via [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html).

```
l1 = {a > b, x > y, m > n};
l2 = {c > d, False, j > k};
Transpose@{l1, l2} (*Gets corresponding pairs of elements*)
DeleteCases[
  % (*This is the shorthand to refer to the previous output and is technically Out[-1]*),
  {_, False} (*The general structure of a pair of elements such that the second one is exactly False*)
]
```

> ```
> (*Output 1*) {{a > b, c > d}, {x > y, False}, {m > n, j > k}}
> ```

> ```
> (*Output 2*) {{a > b, c > d}, {m > n, j > k}}
> ```

Here we first transposed the two lists of vectors so that we get a lists of the corresponding elements in each list.  Then it's a matter of telling *Mathematica* which "forms" or "cases" to look out for and delete them with the fortunately native function `DeleteCases`.

I have a feeling there's another way to do it with [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html), but also that it would take some finagling and, while faster, be more of a *"because you can"* method.

Answer (score 4):

```
l1 = {a > b, x > y, m > n};
l2 = {c > d, False, j > k};
MapThread[
 If[#1 =!= False && #2 =!= False, List[#1, #2], Nothing] &, {l1, l2}]
```

> `{{a > b, c > d}, {m > n, j > k}}`

Answer (score 4):

```
Select[Transpose[{l1,l2}],#[[2]] =!= False &]

(* {{a > b, c > d}, {m > n, j > k}} *)


Select[Transpose[{l3,l4}],#[[2]] =!= False &]

(* {{j > k, m > n}} *)
```

where

```
l1={a>b,x>y,m>n}
l2={c>d,False,j>k}
l3={a>b,c>d,x>y,j>k}
l4={False,False,False,m>n}
```

(Original Answer)

```
Select[Transpose[{l1,l2}],FreeQ[#[[2]], False]&]
(* {{a > b, c > d}, {m > n, j > k}} *)
```

Comment: Or, using the operator form of Select: `Transpose[{l1,l2}]//Select[#[[2]] =!= False &]`